# How do I use map to create a list of circles?

Tags: list, function, haskell

I am trying to create a function which takes in *color* and *number* and returns a list of *Circle* objects (point, radius, color) with changing radius like this:

```
[Circle point 1*(400/n) col, Circle point 2*(400/n) col, ..., Circle point n*(400/n) col]
```

Being new to Haskell, I am struggling with maps and the concept of adding to a list, but I tried with the following simple approach:

```
getCircles :: Color -> Float -> [PictureObject]
getCircles col n = [Circle point (map [1,2..n] * (400/n)) col]
```

Needless to say, it does not work.

Comment: You need to be clearer than "it does not work". What happens? Where do _you_ think the problem lies? etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as though you have misunderstood how `map` works. You provide a function and a list and it maps all elements in the list using the function.

In your case the list is `[1..n]` and the function is 'create a circle using the radius'. So I expect your definition should be using a statement like

```
map (\r -> (Circle point r col)) [1..n]
```

This is using lambda syntax which you might not be familiar with. If not either look it up or use a 'let' statement instead.

Answer (score 0):

A list comprehension would be fairly close to your attempt

```
[Circle point (x * (400/n)) col | x <- [1..n] ]
```